.env file is not being read and returning undefined inside vue js project
I have a simple project using Node.js, Express.js, MSSQL, and Vue.js while managing dependencies with Yarn. While my .env file is being read by express.js, it is not being read in vue js.
My file structure:
outer-dash/
├── server/
│   ├── express.js
|   vue-dash/
    ├── src/
    │   ├── components/
    │   │   └── webdata.vue
    │   │   └── App.vue
    │   └── index.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── .env
    └── yarn.lock
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── .env
│   └── yarn.lock

.env file from outer-dash's root is being read by express.js but the .env file is not being read from vue-dash's root inside of webdata.vue. Both package.json's have dotenv added. But it is not being read inside the vue application.
.env inside vue-app has:
VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api
webdata.vue code:
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Data List</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in webdata" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import axios from "axios";

dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      webdata: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3001/api/web?startDate=2023-04-01&endDate=2023-04-05`
        );
        console.log(response.data);
        this.webdata = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
/* Add your component styles here */
</style>


My package.json:
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "my-dash",
  "productName": "my-dash",
  "description": "My mind-blowing Vue project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "poi",
    "build": "poi build",
    "report": "poi build --bundle-report",
    "serve": "serve dist --single"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "theAuthor",
    "email": "author@authoring.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "offline-plugin": "^4.8.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "poi": "^9.0.0",
    "poi-preset-bundle-report": "^2.0.0",
    "poi-preset-offline": "^9.0.0",
    "serve": "^6.1.0"
  }
}


my poi.config.js:
const path = require("path");
const pkg = require("./package");

module.exports = {
  transformModules: ["dotenv", "axios"],
  entry: ["src/polyfills.js", "src/index.js"],
  html: {
    title: pkg.productName,
    description: pkg.description,
    template: path.join(__dirname, "index.ejs")
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: [
      // Your postcss plugins
    ]
  },
  presets: [
    require("poi-preset-bundle-report")(),
    require("poi-preset-offline")({
      pwa: "./src/pwa.js", // Path to pwa runtime entry
      pluginOptions: {} // Additional options for offline-plugin
    })
  ]
};


console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL); is returning undefined.
How to fix this?

poi has been deprecated for a few years now. it's suggested you migrate to vite which can utilize dotenv with no additional configuration.  for poi I think you need an additional plugin: https://github.com/VitorLuizC/poi-plugin-dotenv

Also dotenv.config() in .vue is a wrong direction, it's supposed to load local .env file with node api, this cannot be done in client-side code
